# Проблемы с подключением css к Django-проекту

Tags: css, django

В чем собственно дело. Я пишу программу которая по запросу пользователя выдает информацию о погоде в. Мне хочется поставить на задний фон видеоролик но у меня не получается это сделать. Папка static была создана. (на всякий случай вот путь
Ниже прикрепляю  код основной страницы `

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'weatherapp/css/style.css/' %">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Video Background</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
        <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">weather com</h5>
        <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Новости</a>
            <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="">Контакты</a>
        </nav>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Документация</a>
    </div>


    <div class="intro">
        <div class="video">
            <video class="video__media" src="video.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        </div>

        <div class="intro__content">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="intro__title"></h1>
                <div class="container mt-5" id = "mark">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5 offset-1">
                <h1>Погодная информация о вашем городе</h1>

                <form action="" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <label for="city">Введите город:</label>
                    {{ form.name }}
                    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Добавить" class="mt-2 btn btn-danger">
                </form>

            </div>

            
            <div class="col-4 offset-1">
                <h1>Информация: </h1>
                {% for info in all_info %}
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <b>Город: </b> {{info.city}} <br>
                            <b>Температура: </b> {{info.temperature}}<sup>o</sup><br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 offset-1">
                            <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{info.icon}}.png" alt="Фото погоды">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
`
```

Далее код  setting.py

`
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",
]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в settings.py прописать такие настройки статики:

```
    STATIC_ROOT = ''
    STATIC_URL = "/static/"
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join('static'),)
```

Так же в строчке `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'weatherapp/css/style.css/' %">` Ты забыл поставить `}` после `%` и убери `/` после `.css`
Должно помочь.